# Calculate $\int_c (1-4x) dx + 2x dy + (1-5y) dz$ using Stoke's Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Let C be the intersection curve between surfaces $z = 3x$ and $x^2+y^2 = 1$, oriented counterclockwise as seen from above. Calculate $$\int_c (1-4x) dx + 2x dy + (1-5y) dz$$
I want to calculate this using **Stoke's theorem**

I found the unit normal vector from the intersection plane to be $n = (-3i + k)/\sqrt10$

Then I found $∇×F = -5i-4j+2k$

I found the dot product and then evaluated $\int^{2\pi}_0\int^1_0 {17\over\sqrt10}$ and got $34\pi\over\sqrt10$

However the correct answer is simply $17\pi$

Please help me to find and understand my error here

Edit:

Ok so from the intersection curve I found $z^2 = 9x^2$ Using this, I found ${z^2\over9} + y^2 = 1$ and the area of this ellipse would be $\sqrt9*\sqrt1*\pi$. So the integrand multiplied by this area would be $(17*3\pi)\over\sqrt10$.
Confirmation of this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The integrand is constant, so the integral is that constant times the area of the enclosed surface. You seem to think that the surface is a circle, but it's not: it's an ellipse, since the plane cuts the cylinder at an angle.

Comment: Might you have forgotten about the Jacobian for the change of variables that you glossed over in your question?

Comment: The intersection does not lie in the $y$-$z$ plane.

Comment: Incidentally, you’ve computed the curl of $F$ incorrectly, but since $n$ has no component in the $\mathbf j$ direction, that error doesn’t contribute anything to your result.

Comment: If Stoke's theorem doesn't work, try Stokes's theorem instead. ;-) (The name of the guy was George Gabriel Stokes.)

Answer (score 1):

As always, these kinds of problems are long, so let's do it!

First, plot the figure:

[image]

As you may see, the intersection is an ellipse. From the integral you show, we have $\mathbf F = (1 -4x) \boldsymbol{\hat \imath} + 2x \boldsymbol{\hat \jmath} + (1 - 5y) \boldsymbol{\hat k}$. Since you want to use the Stokes' theorem:

$$\int_C \mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf r = \iint_S (\nabla \times \mathbf F) \cdot d \mathbf S,$$

we have to find $\nabla \times \mathbf F$:

$$\nabla \times \mathbf F = -5 \boldsymbol{\hat \imath} + 2 \boldsymbol{\hat k}.$$

Now, we have to find the normal vector of that ellipse (which is just the normal vector of the plane). You have already found it:

$$\boldsymbol{\hat{n}} = \sqrt{10}\, \dfrac{-3 \boldsymbol{\hat \imath} + \boldsymbol{\hat k}}{10},$$

so:

$$\iint_S (\nabla \times \mathbf F) \cdot d \mathbf S = \iint_S (\nabla \times \mathbf F) \cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{n}} \, dS = \iint_S (-5 \boldsymbol{\hat \imath} + 2 \boldsymbol{\hat k}) \cdot \left(\sqrt{10}\, \dfrac{-3 \boldsymbol{\hat \imath} + \boldsymbol{\hat k}}{10} \right) dS$$

$$=\dfrac{9 \sqrt{10}}{5} \iint_S dS.$$

The last step is to find the area of that ellipse. Now, the hard part is the following: how do you parametrize the surface of the ellipse? One idea for that may come from the parametrization of curve of the ellipse:

$$\mathbf \Gamma (t) = \cos t \, \boldsymbol{\hat \imath} + \sin t \, \boldsymbol{\hat \jmath} + 3 \sin t \, \boldsymbol{\hat k}, \quad 0 \le t \le 2 \pi. $$

After thinking a lot, a good parametrization of the surface is:

$$\mathbf r (t, s) = \sin t \cos s \,\boldsymbol{\hat \imath} + \sin t \cos t \,\boldsymbol{\hat \jmath} + 3 \sin t \cos s \,\boldsymbol{\hat k}, \quad 0 \le t \le \pi/2,\quad 0 \le s \le 2\pi.$$

I show the plot of the curve and the surface just to be sure:

[image]

The upper limit of $t$ comes from:

$$
\begin{align}
\sin^2 t \, \cos^2 s + \sin^2 t \, \sin^2 s &= 1, \\
\sin^2 t &= 1, \\
t &= \pi /2.
\end{align}
$$

We are doing this because we need:

$$\iint_S dS = \iint_D \lvert \mathbf r_s \times \mathbf r_t \rvert \, dA.$$

After finding the derivatives and the cross product:

$$\lvert \mathbf r_s \times \mathbf r_t \rvert = \sqrt{10} \cos t  \sin t.$$

With that, you can find the area:

$$\iint_D \lvert \mathbf r_s \times \mathbf r_t \rvert \, dA = \int_0^{2\pi} \! \int_0^{\pi /2} \sqrt{10} \cos t \sin t \, dt \, ds = \sqrt{10} \pi.$$

Finally:

$$\iint_S (\nabla \times \mathbf F) \cdot d \mathbf S = \dfrac{9 \sqrt{10}}{5} \iint_S dS = \dfrac{9 \sqrt{10}}{5} \sqrt{10} \pi = 18 \pi.$$